# Nested tab sizing - JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Good morning all. I am very new to JQuery UI and you may be able to help. I have a nested tab created using JQuery UI

[image: When it size in]

[image: When it stretch out]

I have few controls which eventually go into the nested tab. The issue is that, the height of the inner tab is dictated by the number of controls (in rows) which I will be placing into it. Eg: in some case the inner tab height will be within limit of outer tab or sometime it stretch away from inner tab.

Ideally, I am looking for a solution which will have a static height based on user screen which will accommodate all controls within tab and an automatic scroll bar if needed.

Comment: Re-tagged so this question will hopefully get noticed up by people watching the relevant tags

Comment: Could you add an example on jsbin.com or jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Hey, we are not getting exact requirement, can you please put a example or use jsfiddle to show the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If your content is created on page load, you can use  the following to measure the height of the wrapper tab:

```
var outerTabHeight = $("outerTabID").height();
```

Now you need to set the height of the inner tab which can be done like so, so that the height is slightly less than the wrapper tab is this is the way you want it:

```
$("innerTabID").height() = outerTabHeight - 50;
```

The 50 can be increased or decrased to increase or decrease the size according to what's needed.